# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n b_n$ Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

If $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 0$, then does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n b_n$ converge? I think this is false - I don't know about both $a_n$ and $b_n$ but I know that given $a_n=\frac{1}{x}$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So try $a_n=b_n=\frac1{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: What if $a_n, b_n$  have to be different? Can I do $-\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)}$ in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} s_n ~\text{converges} \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to +\infty} s_n = 0,$$

but not viceversa, i.e.

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} s_n = 0 \not\Rightarrow \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} s_n ~\text{converges} .$$

In your case, $s_n =a_n b_n$...